# Azure IoT Hub Telemetry Data to Mobile Application

Tags: azure, react-native, mobile, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to get data from arduino yun to azure iot hub and read data from mobile app. So I created IoT Hub on Azure and able to read telemetry data with nodejs on my computer. It's working good.  But trying to create react app for reading data. What should I do for best way to handle this. I must use react native for mobile application part.

Project info:
Load cell reading data, if change then it will provide info to iot hub as telemetry. Then it should inform mobile application created with react native for users.

For testing using button press right now. Main code for load cell will deploy in the future. Sending data from arduino yun to local computer and pushing with nodejs application to Azure.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  What have you tried so far?  You should show some code and the errors you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve issue with some escape resolutions:

- Used a localhost to get messages from yun and transfer them to iot hub with nodejs backend and libraries.
- Used a webapp for visualize. Also now I am able to make a get request from anywhere on my mobile app load. Integrated that in webapp code with endpoint.
- Also used websocket to get information from webapp to mobile device.
- Created custom png file to show different stats and pressed values to text.

I wish that I can send telemetry from device directly to azure. But couldn't manage to solve that.